# Google Workspace Marketplace only shows first 100 sheets add-ons

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-add-on, google-workspace-marketplace

When I select "Works with Sheets" on [Google Workspace Marketplace](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/category/works-with-spreadsheet), it only shows exactly 100 add-ons. I do not see any "More" button or any other way to see other than these 100. I can't believe that only exactly 100 sheets add-ons were published to the Marketplace.

Is there any way that I can get to browse whatever others are there?

Edit: The suggestion to do a plain Google search of the workspace.google.com domain for "Works with Sheets" does not help. The phrase "Works with Sheets" appears in the sidebar of every page on the Marketplace website. So this search returns every page in the results, including those for drive, gmail, calendar, docs, slides, forms and classroom.

And I cannot find any other terms that narrow it down correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't. You might make a feature request directly to Google by clicking the help button (the circle with a ?) then Send Feedback.

---

One workaround is to use Google (web search), i.e.

[site:https://workspace.google.com "works with sheets"](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:https://workspace.google.com+%22works+with+sheets%22)

1. Go to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
2. On the search box type `site:workspace.google.com "works with sheets"`

Note: The result page might include other pages than the Google Sheets add-on listing pages. You might try refining the search by adding other keywords i.e.

- `"rating"`
- `"overview"`
- `"See, edit, create, and delete all your Google Sheets spreadsheets"`

The above because the Google Workplace Marketplace doesn't offer a way to list / navigate through a complete listing.

P.S. Nowadays there is a type of add-ons that works with Google Sheets, Workspace Add-ons, not Editor Add-ons, that might created using other environments than Google Apps Script. Ref. [Build an add-on in any coding language](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes).

Comment: That Google web search link is what I'm using and what is in my question. I selected that option "Works with sheets". My question is: Is there any way to find more than the 100 that it shows me. I know there are many types of add-ons. I only want to find the sheets ones.

Comment: @JohnPankowicz It looks that you think that Google Workspace Marketplace (`workspace.google.com/marketplace`) and Google (web search / `www.google.com`) are the same web app but they aren't. The question doesn't mention the link that in my answer.

Comment: The link you  gave me is "workspace.google.com" That is what I am using.

Comment: No, it' isn't. The link points to `https://www.google.com/search?q=site:https://workspace.google.com+%22works+with+sheets%22` the text includes the search operator `site:` with `workspace.google.com` as keyword together with `"work with sheets"`.

Comment: Have you clicked the first link in the answer?

Comment: Ok, I see now. SO are you saying that the only way to search for all of the add-ons on Marketplace is to use the Google search engine? Is there no way to find them in Marketplace search?

Comment: AFAIK "...the Google Workplace Marketplace doesn't offer a way to list / navigate through a complete listing."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138306/discussion-between-john-pankowicz-and-ruben).